# regex negative look around with 2 adjacent matches

Tags: javascript, regex

Should be an easy question from someone out there:

**If I run this JavaScript:**

```
var regex = new RegExp("(?!cat)dog(?!cat)","g");
var text =  "catdogcat catdogdog catdogdogcat".replace(regex,"000");
console.log(text);
```

**It ouputs this:**

```
catdogcat cat000000 cat000dogcat
```

But I though it should output this:

```
catdogcat cat000000 cat000000cat
```

Why isn't the second "dog" in `catdogdogcat` replaced with `000`?

**EDIT:** I want to replace "dog" whenever it doesn't have cat on BOTH sides. In `catdogdogcat`, BOTH dogs fulfill this requirement and so they should be replaced. Obviously I don't Understand these negative look arounds...

Comment: Because it's followed by `cat`, which the second `(?!cat)` rules out. You might want to explain what exactly you are trying to accomplish with the two lookarounds, as I suspect the first one doesn't do what you want, either.

Comment: In my experience, most REGEXes that use look-aheads somewhere in the pattern other than at the end of it do not perform as the user expects.

Comment: @Utkanos really? there are actually quite a few use cases for lookaheads inside patterns.

Comment: Hmm. I've edited my answer with what I'm trying to do. I think I need to readup on on negative look arounds...

Comment: @JoeRocc ah yeah, that's what I thought. That complicates matters quite a bit. See my answer.

Comment: @m.buettner - I didn't say they didn't have their uses, I just said in my experience, except where used at the end of the patterns, the result was not normally what the developer (unless he's of sufficient level with regular expressions) expects. As is the case with this question.

Comment: @Utkanos fair enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems with your approach.

1. **Your first lookahead needs to be a lookbehind.** When you write `(?!cat)`, the engine checks that the next three characters are `cat` and then resets to where it started (that's how it **looks** ahead), and then you try to match `dog` at those same three characters. Therefore, the lookahead doesn't add anything: if you can match `dog` you obviously can't match `cat` at the same position. What you want is a lookbehind `(?<!cat)` that checks that the preceding characters are not `cat`. Unfortunately, JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind.
2. **You want to logically *OR* the two lookarounds.** In your case, if either lookaround fails, it causes the pattern fail. Hence both requirements (of *not* having `cat` at either end) need to be fulfilled. But you actually want to *OR* that. If lookbehinds were supported that would rather look like `(?<!cat)dog|dog(?!cat)` (note that the alternation splits the entire pattern apart). But as I said, lookbehinds are not supported. The reason why you seemd to have *OR*ed the two lookarounds in your first `catdogdog` bit is that the preceding `cat` was simply not checked (see point 1).

How to work around lookbehinds then? Kolink's answer suggests `(?!cat)...dog`, which puts the lookaround at the position where a `cat` would start, and uses a lookahead. This has two new problems: it cannot match a `dog` at the beginning of the string (because the three characters in front are required. And it cannot match two consecutive `dog`s because matches cannot overlap (after matching the first `dog`, the engine requires three new characters which `...`, which would consume the next `dog` before actually matching `dog` again).

Sometimes you can work around it by reverse both pattern and string, hence turning the lookbehind into a lookahead - but in your case that would turn the lookahead at the end into a lookbehind.

### The regex-only solution

We have to be a bit cleverer. Since matches cannot overlap, we could try to match `catdogcat` explicitly, without replacing it (hence skipping them in the target string), and then just replace all `dog`s we find. We put the two cases in an alternation, so they are both tried at every position in the string (with the `catdogcat` option taking precedence, although it doesn't really matter here). The problem is how to get conditional replacement strings. But let's look at what we've got so far:

```
text.replace(/(catdog)(?=cat)|dog/g, "$1[or 000 if $1 didn't match]")
```

So in the first alternative we match a `catdog` and capture it into group `1` and check that there is another `cat` following. In the replacement string we simply write the `$1` back. The beauty is, if the second alternative matched, the first group will be unused and hence be an empty string the replacement. The reason why we only match `catdog` and use a lookahead instead of matching `catdogcat` right away is again overlapping matches. If we used `catdogcat`, then in the input `catdogcatdogcat` the first match would consume everything until and including the second `cat`, hence the second `dog` could not be recognized by the first alternative.

Now the only question is, how do we get a `000` into the replacement, if we used the second alternative.

Unfortunately, we can't conjure up conditional replacements that are not part of the input string. The trick is to add a `000` to the end of the input string, capture that in a lookahead if we find a `dog`, and then write that back:

```
text.replace(/$/, "000")                            
    .replace(/(catdog)(?=cat)|dog(?=.*(000))/g, "$1$2")
    .replace(/000$/, "")
```

The first replacement adds `000` to the end of the string.

The second replacement matches either `catdog` (checking that another `cat` follows) and captures it into group `1` (leaving `2` empty) or matches `dog` and captures `000` into group `2` (leaving group `1` empty). Then we write `$1$2` back, which will be either the unadorned `catdog` or `000`.

The third replacement gets rid of our extraneous `000` at the end of the string.

### The callback solution

If you are not a fan of preparing the regex, and the lookahead in the second option, you can instead use a slightly simpler regex with a replacement callback:

```
text.replace(/(catdog)(?=cat)|dog/g, function(match, firstGroup) {
    return firstGroup ? firstGroup : "000"
})
```

With the version of `replace` the supplied function gets called for each match and its return value is used as the replacement string. The functions first parameter is the entire match, the second parameter is the first capturing group (which will be `undefined` if the group doesn't participate in the match) and so on...

So in the replacement callback we are free to conjure up our `000` if `firstGroup` is undefined (i.e. the `dog` option matched) or just return the `firstGroup` if it is present (i.e. the `catdogcat` option matched). This is a bit more concise and possibly easier to understand. However, the overhead of calling the function makes it [significantly slower](http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-callback) (although whether that matters depends on how often you want to do this). Pick your favorite!

Comment: +1 for taking all the time to write such detailed and good explanation.

Comment: WOW! Thanks so much - I really appreciate the time you put in to write that.

Comment: Nice answer. A note about performance, though. On Firefox 36, the performance is not that different between the two methods, and I'd suggest the callback method over the regex method anyway for code clarity...

Answer (score 1):

Your regex simplifies to `dog(?!cat)` (because the first lookbehind consumes nothing), so it is replacing any instance of `dog` that is not followed by `cat`.

Try the regex `(?!cat).{3}dog(?!cat)`

Comment: That will still not yield the desired output. I think the OP wants to "OR" the two lookarounds instead of "AND"ing them. Plus, this here cannot replace consecutive `dog`s, because the matches would overlap.

Comment: `s/lookbehind/lookahead/`. I assume this is what you meant?