# Match string which doesn't start with

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
var str = "Hello world, &nbsp;hello &gt;world, hello world!";
```

... and I'd like to replace all the hellos with e.g. bye and world with earth, except the words that start with &nbsp or &gt. Those should be ignored. So the result should be:

```
bye earth, &nbsp;hello &gt;world, bye earth!
```

Tried to this with

```
str.replace(/(?!\&nbsp;)hello/gi,'bye'));
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(?!...)` is a look**ahead**. So it looks at the same characters where you want to match `hello`. What you need is a lookbehind.

Unfortunately, JavaScript does not support lookbehinds. You could however reverse the string and the pattern:

```
reverse = function(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}

str = reverse(reverse(str).replace(/olleh(?!;psbn&)/gi, 'eyb'));
```

A bit of a hack, I admit.

Alternatively, a solution [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17341622/1633117) could be applied. It relies on the fact that matches cannot overlap:

```
str = str.replace(/(&nbsp;hello)|hello/ig, function(match, firstGroup) {
    return firstGroup ? firstGroup : "bye"
});
```

However, using a slightly more arcane trick (as in the linked answer) you can improve efficiency by about a factor of 2:

```
str = str.replace(/$/, "bye")                            
         .replace(/(&nbsp;hello)|hello(?=.*(bye))/g, "$1$2")
         .replace(/bye$/, "")
```

For a full explanation, see the other post (as this question is essentially a duplicate).

As for performance, the reversal one is obviously the slowest, as it has to handle an array (twice). As for the others, the callback one is the fastest, and the regex only one is somewhere in between. So both for performance and readability, I'd recommend the callback solution. (see [benchmarks](http://jsperf.com/mimicking-lookbehind))

Comment: For some reason, all the benchmarks are showing callback topping off regex only method by factor of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you'd use a [negative look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but that's not supported in JavaScript. you can do this though:

```
var str = "Hello world, &nbsp;hello &gt;world, hello world!";
str.replace(/(&(?:nbsp|gt);)?(?:(hello)|world)/gi, 
    function($0, $1, $2){ return $1 ? $0 : $2 ? 'bye' : 'earth'; });
// bye earth, &nbsp;hello &gt;world, bye earth!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that capturing all words which begin with `&nbsp;` or `&gt;` first:

```
var str = "Hello world, &nbsp;hello &gt;world, hello world!";

str = str.replace(/(&(?:gt|nbsp);\w+)|(\bhello\b)|(\bworld\b)/gi, function (match,p1,p2,p3) { 
    if (p1) return p1;
    if (p2) return 'bye';
    if (p3) return 'earth'; });

    console.log(str);
```